# Which is the recommended driver for my graphics card?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have a Dell Latitude E6500 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and after a fresh reinstall, I notice some sluggishness, which is probably due to the video drivers. 
My graphics card is a NVIDIA Quadro NVS 160M. When I open Additional Drivers, there are various options but I don't know which is the best one. Many thanks.

This is what I get with `sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G98M [Quadro NVS 160M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f2000000-f3ffffff ioport:df00(size=128) memory:f4000000-f401ffff
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to try them for yourself. In general, use the stable (rather then experimental) driver with the highest (version) number. If that fails, try the experimental driver.

You can always changes drivers if you do not like the current driver, but it does require rebooting between drivers.

Comment: Okay I will try them all. Unfortunately, none of them says (stable).

Comment: Highest number then ;)

Comment: What is "NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library?" It shows up in the Additional Drivers window, together with Accelerated Graphics Driver (version 173 & 304-updates)

Comment: That is the driver for your graphics card. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: Ok, now I got confused so "NVIDIA binary Xorg driver, kernel module and VDPAU library" is the same as nvidia-304-updates?
See: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304-updates
They are different entries in the Add driver window: which one shall I install?

Comment: I also found this: http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/70743/en-us
downloadable as a .run file

Comment: lol, install the nvidia binary according to the link I gave you.

Comment: I tried them all, it's still very slow